# Wireless Transfer ,How to create hotspot

Tags: wifi, file-transfer, wifi-hotspot

How can I enable hotspot from my laptop using terminal? I don't need internet connection to do that. I want to set up a server so that I can transfer my files from my laptop to my mobile or another laptops. Is it possible using terminal? I  have used `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` but for that I have to either connect to my mobile hotspot or any other common shared network. But I can't upload in laptop. Only download.

(Main problem is to create hotspot using terminal. I use DEEPIN 15.3 debian based)

Comment: Dont understand.. why people vote negative if they dont understand matter :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a snap [package](http://www.howtogeek.com/252047/how-to-install-and-manage-snap-packages-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts/) (it's a new packaging technique created by Ubuntu developers) called `wifi-ap`. You can use it from terminal to create a wireless network, and even share internet if you want.

To install the package : `snap install wifi-ap`.
Then you have to configure the access point with this command `wifi-ap.config`.

To be able to install and manage snap packages, you have first to install `snapd` with the command `sudo apt-get install snapd`.
Then, add this line  to your `~/.bashrc` : `export PATH=/snap/bin:$PATH`, to be able to call the installed snaps from terminal.

Comment: Thanx @Sidahmed

Comment: No problem, glad I could help dude. You tried it yet ??

Comment: haha not actually..i moved to mac os... But will try on frnds laptop :) @Sidahmed

Comment: do you know how to use Google drive API to attach upload action to button ..where to start in eclipse :/.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I have no idea